# Правильное написание дат

Tags: единственное-множественное-число

В каком числе надо употребить "год" в словосочетании такого типа: "ноябрь 1977 - сентябрь 1979 годов/года"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: *ноябрь 1977 — сентябрь 1979 год**а**.*
Но то же без месяцев: *1977–1979 год**ы**/гг.*
Или ещё примеры: *зимы 1950-х год**ов**, июни 2000-х год**ов*** (правда, такой контекст довольно редок).

Слово *год* здесь относится к сентябрю и косвенно к 1977 году, но никак не к ноябрю. А поскольку 1979 год *единственный* и сентябрь 1979 года также единственный, то не может быть *сентября 1979 годов,* как если бы сентябрь в 79-м был не один или 79-й год наступил бы ещё хотя бы раз.

Недавно прослушал аудиозапись передачи ["Как это по-русски?"](https://www.radiorus.ru/brand/57203/episode/1900251) (интересовала пара австриец/австрияк — австрийка/австриячка) — там с 9:26 ***аналогичный*** вопрос про число в случае с рубежом веков. Там *XIX — начало XX века,* но можно поменять и на *конец/середину XIX — начало XX века,* например.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё ясно.

Comment: Не за что! Рад был помочь. :)

Comment: @РаульАм: дополнил ответ на всякий случай.